# Audio Message Player like WhatsApp in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, chat

i Want to make audio message player in table view cell for chat app in swift does any one one have solution please help

Comment: See Help Center to find out what type of questions are acceptable here.

Comment: Have you found a solution bro?? can you share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for it you have to set audio url accounting to collectionView cell and play on  did select event or you can also create custom UI for tableview cell.
attached url of some frameworks with help of it you can achieve the desire output.

- https://github.com/yoheimuta/RxMusicPlayer
- https://github.com/jorgenhenrichsen/SwiftAudio
- https://github.com/delannoyk/AudioPlayer
- https://github.com/tbaranes/AudioPlayerSwift
- https://github.com/tanhakabir/SwiftAudioPlayer

Comment: i have tried this but its not work in cells perfectly index and play pause etc

Comment: can you show the code ?

Comment: i want to use the SwiftAudio this can you explain it that how it can be used in table view cells

Comment: add code of SwiftAudio to play audio in your cell file and it will work

Comment: there is a problem in adding files to player from array

Comment: show your code ....